# Angular mock multiple HTTP calls

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, karma-jasmine, angular-httpclient

I have one service which is returning the forkjoin of multiple http calls. I wanted to test this scenario.

```
    class CommentService{
     addComments(){

let ob1 = Observable.of({});
    let ob2 = Observable.of({});
if(any condition)
        ob1 = {this.http.post('/url/1')};
if(any condition)
            ob2 = {this.http.post('/url/2'};
        return Observable.forkJoin(ob1,ob2)
           }
     }
```

Above is my service class. How can i mock the http calls.

```
describe("CommentService", () => {
  let httpClient: HttpClient;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [CommentService]
    });

    httpClient = TestBed.get(HttpClient);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  it('addComments() call with normal and gate', inject([CommentService], (service: CommentService) => {


    let cmts = service.addComments();

    const reqGateComment = httpTestingController.expectOne('/url/1');
    expect(reqGateComment.request.method).toEqual('POST');

    const reqFactComment = httpTestingController.expectOne('/url/2');
    expect(reqFactComment.request.method).toEqual('POST');

    reqGateComment.flush({});
    reqFactComment.flush({});


    httpTestingController.verify();

    cmts.subscribe(results=>{
       expect(results.length).toEqual(2);
    });

  }));


});
```

I am getting the below test fail. 
CommentService addFactsAndComments() call with normal and gate

Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL:

```
 '/url/1", found none.
```

Comment: any updates on this?

Answer (score 4):

I had   a similar problem and I solved it using fakeAsync.

```
it('addComments() call with normal and gate', fakeAsync( inject([CommentService], (service: CommentService) => {

    service.addComments().subscribe(results=>{
        expect(results.length).toEqual(2);
     });

    const reqGateComment = httpTestingController.expectOne('/url/1');
    expect(reqGateComment.request.method).toEqual('POST');
    reqGateComment.flush({});

    tick(10000);

    const reqFactComment = httpTestingController.expectOne('/url/2');
    expect(reqFactComment.request.method).toEqual('POST');
    reqFactComment.flush({});


    httpTestingController.verify();

  })));
```

Comment: I'm currently on Angular 11 and I can confirm this works for me as well

Comment: it does work, but why in heavens name mocking only works if called after the tested function... where is this on docs? :cry:

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are wrapping the observables created by the `HttpClient` in new ones by using the `of` method.

By doing

```
joined$ = forkJoin(obs$(post1$),obs$(post2$))
```

*Note: $ stands for observable*

You create a new observable that:

- Subscribes to the outer `obs$`
- Waits for them to complete,
- Collects their last emited values (in this case post1$ and post2$)
- Returns the collected values as an array in the order of the source streams

Because we only subscribed to the outer `obs$`, your test is failing with

> '/url/1", found none.

As we never subscribed to the inner post$, meaning that the requests werent sent.

Change your service method to:

```
addComments(){    
    const ob1 = this.http.post('/url/1');
    const ob2 = this.http.post('/url/2');

    return Observable.forkJoin(ob1,ob2);
 }
```

Comment: I updated my code. It is still throwing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `addComments` and subscribe to the returned observable before you invoke `expectOne`. Only on subscription will the `httpClient` requests be triggered

That's the core issue here that's causing the test failure

You're right not to use fakeAsync btw as using HttpClientTestingModule is synchronous